# Twitter Bootstrap's Dropdown menu not working in Nav-Tabs NavBar in JS Fiddle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I've been having so many problems getting this Twitter Bootstrap Nav bar to work in JS Fiddle; I finally got it to render the way I wanted nothing is dropping down from my dropdown menu (under the tab "Community")- I don't know what the problem is. I got it to work functionally when I did it in a text-editor, my code seems to be exactly the same, but in JS Fiddle (where I need it to work) when I press the button, nothing drops down & I can't figure out why, I've tried changing so many things- if anyone can help or direct me to why this isn't working, I'd so so appreciate it (I tried changing the li to a div which ruined the styling of the whole thing, I tried adding data-toggle to each `<a>` element in the dropdown, also nothing, I just don't know what to do at this point or what I'm doing wrong. I hope I have enough/the right external resources added to this (in JS Fiddle, you can't add them to the html or it doesn't render correctly). Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here's a link to my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tamara6666/2cup6cno/
Heres' my code:

```
<header>
</header>

<body>
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <icon class="fa fa-home"></icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Community</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Member Activity</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Lists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Groups</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pet Help</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pets for Sale</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Pet Services</a></li>
  </ul>
<main>
<div id='content' class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>    

</main>
</body>
```

Comment: You may want to run your html through a validator. And you're abusing `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`<script type="text/javascript">$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();</script>
</body>`

Also don't forget to add jquery before including bootstrap.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: wait, I don't understand- that looks like J Query code- where do I add " $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown(): " - in the JavaScript panel as a J Query function (where I'd add a J Query function) or in the html above the <body> tag? I'm not sure what a "body clod" tag is (I'm sorry, I'm kinda new to all of this). Thanks @Oddadmix

Comment: You don't need that code, you can just add `data-toggle="tab"` to the `<a>`'s that you want to trigger the tab panes.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu if you check the  https://jsfiddle.net/Tamara6666/2cup6cno/ you will find that jquery is missing.

Comment: Agreed. But don't need the added script, it can be triggered by using `data-toggle="tab"`.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu it depends if the includes are before or after the markup render.

Comment: thank you guys- I saw @Oddamix 's answer first (which worked so Thank You) .Thanks for all of the help both of you- I had this all working in my text editor but needed it to work in JS Fiddle & I felt like I was rlly loosing my mind not figuring out why it wouldn't work in JS Fiddle. Thank you So much, I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: And, @Chris Yongchu ,  just adding data-toggle="tab" to the <a> element seems easier &  neater than adding all of that code- I think I'll also try that just so I learn it to use for next time, I'm going to give it a shot... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include jQuery, as Bootstrap.js requires jQuery. If you open the browser console, the error is caught there `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Adding jQuery will fix the issue you're having. I've revised your fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/2cup6cno/9/) to include the other tab panes. You can modify them or remove it, completely up to you.

Check out the examples on Bootstrap on the correct markup and usage of using tabs at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: do u know how I can get rid of or change the color or that dark line in between the "home pane" and the nav tabs (while keeping the color behind them dark grey)? Ideally I'd like to change it to another color- I've been trying so many different css selectors but can not find which one it is for that line (like doing border collapse which messes up the layout of the navs), trying to remove borders, etc. but i want to keep the layout as is... I've been trying to figure it out for days... You seem to know what's up... Thanks

Comment: @TamaraFrankel, glad to hear you figured it out.